# How to directly select nodes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I ever select node in C# from `System.XML` library.

When I got two lever lower from current element.

```
 XmlElement sampleElement = (XmlElement)root;
 XmlNodeList sampleNodeList = sampleElement.SelectNodes("test/code");
```

So I could get inside of `test/code`.

However after I define on the root like below.

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/example"
xmlns="http://test.com/schema/"
```

Then I can not bring directly `test/code` like this.
I have to use just one level down.

Does anyone have a better idea for this?

Thank you !

Comment: Do you *have* to use `XmlDocument`/`XmlElement`? LINQ to XML is much nicer... and makes namespace handling simpler too.

Comment: At this moment yes, but thank you for your information I will study that :)

Comment: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I just use single node and go down one level.

Comment: Use GetElementsByTagName instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you asking, but this is what we used to do.

Let's say you have an XmlDocument, to select any kind of note you could do this, it really is in the XPATH

`Xmlnode _node = XmlDocument.selectsinglenode("//code")`, that will find you first encountered "code" node.

`_node.InnerText` should give you the value of the node.

Make sure that when you define your root those elements are attributes inside the ROOT node not nodes.